# Using Crank-Nicolson to solve Non-Linear Schrödinger equation in Python

Tags: numerics, ode, crank-nicolson

I aim to solve the (non-linear) Schrodinger equation using the Crank-Nicolson method in Python. Here are my two functions.

```
def diags(N, dt, dx):
    Adiag = sp.empty(N)
    Asup = sp.empty(N)
    Asub = sp.empty(N)
    bdiag = sp.empty(N)
    bsup = sp.empty(N)
    bsub = sp.empty(N)

    Adiag.fill(1 + dt/dx**2)
    Asup.fill(-dt/(2*dx**2))
    Asub.fill(-dt/(2*dx**2))
    bdiag.fill(1 - dt/dx**2)
    bsup.fill(dt/(2*dx**2))
    bsub.fill(dt/(2*dx**2))

    A = sp.sparse.spdiags([Adiag, Asup, Asub], [0, 1, -1],N, N)
    b = sp.sparse.spdiags([bdiag, bsup, bsub], [0, 1, -1],N, N)
    return A, b

def crankNicolson(psi, dt, V, A, b, g=0):
    psi = np.exp(-dt*(V + g*np.abs(psi.reshape(-1))**2))*psi
    psi = sp.sparse.linalg.bicg(A, b*psi.reshape(-1).astype(np.complex128))[0]
    return psi
```

which has been taken from [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/6708/). However, the given link aims to propagate in imaginary time, therefore I would need to have $ dt \rightarrow -i dt $ in order to convert the code to propagate in real time instead. This can simply be done by putting `-1j*dt` as an input into the functions instead of just `dt`.

To put simply, the function `diags()` is run once to obtain A and b, which are then inputs for the function `crankNicolson()`, which in turn is run within a loop to iterate the process and propagate it in time.

However when I do this and propagate, my situation does not evolve in time but remains stationary. Can anyone see what's up with it? It absolutely should evolve, as I compare it to an explicit-midpoint method of mine which evolves in time well using the exact same input parameters.

Some additional information:

The equation in dimensionless form is
$$
i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi + V \psi + g|\psi|^2\psi
$$

where the $V$ term is a self-consistent potential which is calculated separately (it is not important for this question as it is definitely correct), and $g$ is the coupling constant.
The boundary conditions are that $\psi(0) = 0$ and $\psi(L) = 0$, owing to the fact that this is a decomposition of a spherically symmetric system with wavefunction $\phi$ according to $\phi = \psi/x$ (though this detail is perhaps not important).

The initial condition is a half-Gaussian, given by $\psi = x \alpha \exp(-x^2/\beta)$, which is centred on $x=0$.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781911/2451

Comment: Does your code work correctly with no nonlinearity or potential? If things aren't working, try to simplify until it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the link to a Colab notebook implementing Crank-Nicolson method in a finite difference method discretization of your problem:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u1G4Tk7ssk9BJYCksR5GrADkdCGWfC2p?usp=sharing